# How to move audio files from internal storage to external SD card permanently?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, samsung-galaxy-j7

OK so, I have a Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime and just recently have purchased an SD card.

I want to move 117 audio files from my internal storage to (external) SD card without having those files on my actual phone. I tried moving them to the SD card and then deleting them from the internal storage but that just deletes everything from the SD card **AND** from the phone itself, so I copied them (if there even is a difference) and the deleted them from the internal storage but that didn't work either.

Pleeeeeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaaaaaase heeeeeeeeeeeeeeelp!!

p.s. If anyone knows how to change the download path to my sd card that'll be really helpful.
*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 0):

Basically just get a sd card reader and a usb cable and copy it to your computer then unplug it then delete the file on computer then copy it onto the sd card then put it on then you are done then i stop typing then